# C++ HelloWorld not printing correctly

Tags: c++, eclipse, console

I just installed c/c++ development tools for my eclipse and everything is working except no text is being printed in the console when I run the hello world program, but I receive no errors. I'm really stumped, anyone know why this is?

[image]
**Edit:**

Ok I realized if that debug it, it works correctly, but not if I run it, any ideas there?

Comment: You program seems fine. How about your eclipse? You could try some sample code see if it works properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using a 64-bit version of Eclipse? If so, that might be your problem. The 64-bit version doesn't do console output. *sigh* Try downgrading to the 32-bit version.

On SO, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959908/c-program-cannot-display-output-to-console-view-in-eclipse).
On the Eclipse forums, check [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/197552/).

Comment: Ah, I am, that stinks. Guess I have to downgrade to 32bit. :(

Answer (score 2):

Does a window pop up then disappear? It could be printing it in console then closing as soon as it hits the end of the code...

Answer (score 1):

try to make your code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespase std;

int main()
{
  cout << "helllo, world" << endl;
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set the environment so the eclipse can find the c++ compiler.
Go to `Computer` and right click `Properties` -> `advanced system settings` -> `enviroment variables`.
Scroll down in `system variables` and find the `path` (it is named so). Press `edit` and append in the `path` the value `C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;`. You will have something like `C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;C:\programfiles.......`.
Then start again the eclipse the problem should have been solved.