# Eclipse C++ see output only when debugging

Tags: eclipse, console, eclipse-cdt, output

I've created c++ "Hello World" sample project in eclipse using "cygwin GCC" Toolchain.

Project Compiles and run.The problem is that I don't see my "Hello World" Output in console below.

The Interesting fact is when I run my project in "Debug" mode , I do see an output after I execute :

```
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl;
```

How can I see my console output in simple "Run mode" ?
I'm Using Eclipse Juno...

Comment: Are you using 64-bit Eclipse by any chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @**einpoklum** , following your links I've found a solution !

Make sure to run Eclipse as Administrator ! That's it :)

Of course if it still doesn't work , refer to @**einpoklum** answer.

Comment: Actually, that should _not_ be necessary. After all, many users can't use administrator privileges. Can you tell what you need them for, exactly?

Comment: Well... I don't fully understand why I need Administrator privileges. But it does solves the problem. Found it here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9779984/930171

Comment: It just shifts the problem, it doesn't solve it, because you don't really need admin privileges. You need to prevent Eclipse or GCC or what-not from trying something which requires admin privileges.

Comment: Ugh finally. Thank you for this answer. It would be great to not need it but I don't care to figure out the source issue like others suggest I just want it to work.

Answer (score 2):

This is a widely-reported problem with multiple possible solutions.

- It might be your PATH environment variable. Make sure it contains `C:\Cygwin\bin` or wherever you installed Cygwin to. If that's missing, you might not be able to load the `cygwin1.dll` and Eclipse doesn't report that well enough.
- Maybe it's due to output buffering. Try adding

  ```
  setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
  setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);`
  ```

  at the start of your main function.
- Some people [suggest](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/197552/630039/) trying a 32-bit version of Eclipse (and JRE). I would try to avoid going down that road...

Comment: I've added C:\Cygwin\bin to my PATH environment variable,nothing have changed.Those buffer commands didn't help either.Just to make things clear , I create a new C++ project from template (Hello World) using cygwin toolchain.