# Eclipse (c++) doesn't run programs

Tags: c++, eclipse, console, return

I'm trying to work with c++ on eclipse and I can't even run the hello world program provided by default.

I'm using the mingw g++ compiler and the file is obviously compiled succesfully.

But when I try to run it (debug or release versions) it just shows nothing on the console.
After finding out on internet that there's a bug in eclipse that doesn't show output stream on the console. I decided to redirect the stream on a file.

The file is empty as well.

I noticed in the debug tab that the program is returning `-1073741515.`

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: we are going to need more information

Comment: Did you try to run it from cmd manually?

Comment: would help if you posted the hello world source and also a screen shot of your eclipse ide. also on the left hand side of eclipse check if the .exe got created.

Comment: the code is the default template... but if you want it: int main(){printf("hi\n");return0;}

Comment: Works fine in Eclipse CDT 8.1.1 on Linux. Have you tried to compile and run from the command line. Maybe your toolchain is broken.

Comment: @vitaut: i'm on windows

Comment: @user2076450: Checking the compiler from the command line is useful anyway.

Comment: @user2076450: Isn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959908/c-program-cannot-display-output-to-console-view-in-eclipse?rq=1) the same problem as yours? I'm encountering the same issue right now.

Answer (score -2):

As general and unrelated advice. Don't use eclipse. Use Emacs as editor and find c++ mode on it. You will get tired at first but will live happily after this.